# What is the difference between AuthenticateRequest and AuthorizeRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, authentication, authorization

Can you explain the differences between `HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest` and `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest` in `ASP.NET MVC 3` please? When will they occur? Assume this scenario:

My `User` has a property called `IsBanned` and I want to check his/her `IsBanned` property in each request. If it was `true`, I redirect the `User` to an error page. But not for all requests, just requests that their action signed by `[Authorize]` attribute. OK, atthis type of actions, will `HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest` occur or `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest` or anything else?

I know I can check this property in `SignIn|LogOn` action. But I means this:

- A user requests logging in
- I check the property `IsBanned` and it was `false`
- The user logged in
- User view some pages of site
- The admin banned the user (while he is logged in)
- User requests a page (action) that have `[Authorize]` attribute
- User is logged in (before this. remember?)
- So I have to show the requested page
- But the user give a banned flag by admin
- How can I prevent user from viewing requested page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need to deal with either of `HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest` or `HttpApplication.AuthorizeRequest`. I would solve it by using a custom `Authorize` Attribute.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
            bool authorizerPrimarily = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

            if(authorizedPrimarily){
               return user_not_banned;
            }

            return authorizerPrimarily;
        }
}
```

You can get user's name from `httpContext.User.Identity.Name`. Use it to grab data from database.

**Update for comment-1**

To redirect banned users to a specific page, you may do this:

```
if(authorizedPrimarily){
   if(user_banned){
      httpContext.Response.Redirect("url of banned message");
      return false;
   }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 OK thanks good idea. So how can I redirect user to a specified page e.g. a page with a message: you are banned!

Comment: Using the process I specified will only redirect you to login page if the user is banned.I have done something similar like redirecting to a different page. You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931659/custom-authentication-attribute-seems-to-work-fine-but-is-there-any-drawbacks) I asked. Although no one replied.